# Кнопки next prev для страниц внутри категории(начиная с первой страницы обе кнопки)

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Добрый день, помогите!
На Wordpress нужно сделать кнопки Next/Prev внутри записей категории. Что бы эти кнопки отображались всегда. например внутри категории 5 страниц, когда отображается первая что бы кнопка prev была и при нажатии перешла на 5 страницу, а next на вторую. Стандартными средствами кнопка Prev отображать будет только со второй страницы. А на первой и второй кнопок этих нету!

Comment: Какой смысл ставить ссылку на самого себя? Это loop получается бесконечный. Не боитесь проблем с сео и недопониманий юзеров?

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!
Я по-быстрому накидал тут небольшой кусочек кода. Конечно, его лучше завернуть в виде функции и разместить в functions.php для последующего использования где угодно:

```
    //Формируем аргументы для запроса массива постраничной навигации
$args = array(
    'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),  
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'type' => 'array',
    'prev_next' => false,
);

//Получаем постраничную навигацию в виде массива
$result = paginate_links( $args );
//Получаем количество элементов в массиве
$pagCount = count($result);
//Текущая страница в постраничной навигации
$current_page = max( 1, get_query_var('paged') );
//Вся постраничная навигация
$simple_pagination = "";
$counter = 0;
foreach ($result as $simPage)
{
    $counter = $counter + 1;
    $simple_pagination .= '<br><a href="/page/'.$counter.'">'.$counter.'</a>';

}

//Выводим ссылки на предыдущую и следующую страницу
if($current_page == 1)
{
    $pagination .= '<br><a href="/page/'.($pagCount).'">Предыдущая страница</a>';
}
else
{
    $pagination .= '<br><a href="/page/'.($current_page-1).'">Предыдущая страница</a>';
}

//Добавляем "внутренние" страницы в постраничную навигацию
$pagination .= $simple_pagination;

if($current_page == $pagCount)
{
    $pagination .= '<br><a href="/page/1">Следующая страница</a>';
}
else
{
    $pagination .= '<br><a href="/page/'.($current_page+1).'">Следующая страница</a>';
}

echo $pagination;
```

Всё основано на функции [paginate_links()](http://wp-kama.ru/function/paginate_links) самого Wordpress'a